# MySQL: Select row by id with previous and next rows by date

Tags: mysql

I have this table:

```
update_id | project_id | content | date
------------------------------------------------------
1         | 1          | text... | 2011-12-20 22:10:30 
2         | 2          | text... | 2011-12-20 22:10:30 
3         | 2          | text... | 2011-12-21 22:10:30 
4         | 2          | text... | 2011-12-22 22:10:30 
5         | 2          | text... | 2011-12-23 22:10:30
```

My current query is:

```
SELECT update_id, project_id, content, date
FROM update
WHERE update_id = 2
AND project_id = 2
ORDER BY date DESC
LIMIT 1
```

But besides the selected row, I want to get also the previous and next row based on the date column (for a specific project_id), so I can show 'previous update' and 'next update' links (if available).

Comment: Does the table have a primary key? This would make it easier.

Comment: You're gonna need two queries, I'm afraid.

Comment: @Eugen: update_id is primary key, I updated the question.

Comment: @Sergei: Really? I have seen much more complicated things done using one query.

Answer (score 1):

First approach. This select return 3 rows. Your selected row and a row for a previous date and anoder row for next date:

```
SELECT * FROM ( 
 SELECT 
   'THIS' as update_time,
   update_id, 
   project_id, 
   content, 
   date
 FROM 
   `update`
 WHERE 
   update_id = 2 AND project_id = 2
 ORDER 
   BY date DESC
 LIMIT 1
) TT
UNION
SELECT * FROM ( 
 SELECT 
   'PREVIOUS'  as update_time,
   update_id, 
   project_id, 
   content, 
   date
 FROM 
   `update`
 WHERE 
   update_id <> 2 AND project_id = 2 and
   date <= (select date from `update` where update_id = 2)
 ORDER 
   BY date DESC
 LIMIT 1
) TP
UNION
SELECT * FROM ( 
 SELECT 
   'NEXT'  as update_time,
   update_id, 
   project_id, 
   content, 
   date
 FROM 
   `update`
 WHERE 
   update_id <> 2 AND project_id = 2 and
   date >= (select date from `update` where update_id = 2)
 ORDER 
   BY date ASC
 LIMIT 1
) TN
```

Comment: It gets more correct (per OP's question) if you add AND project_id = 2 to each WHERE, and change each were into WHERE.

Comment: Im getting: syntax error near 'update were update_id = 2) ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1 ) TP UNION SEL' at line 28

Comment: @Jonathan, refresh screen. I have changed 'were' by 'where' as Amadan pointed to me. Also remember that 'update' is a reserved word.

Comment: @Jonathan, sorry about previous mistakes.

Comment: @danihp: Is there a way not to repeat 'update_id = 2' and 'project_id = 2' that many times? It can be a problem to pass those params so many times using CodeIgniter Database Class

Comment: With a single query and acceptable performance I don't know how to avoid this. Perhaps you can split query in 3 querys.

Answer (score 0):

You need 2 sub selects.. but now to link them.

```
SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 as place, update_id, project_id, content, date, () as previous, () as next, (SELECT @rownum:=0)
```

where the blank () are replaced by subqueries of the same form.

Comment: blank () are replaced by subqueries of the same form?? I dont get it.

Comment: with the rownum trick so you can reference the previous and next dates for the top level query.