# MySQL: Dynamically add columns to query results

Tags: mysql

I have this table:

```
update_id | project_id | content | date
------------------------------------------------------
1         | 1          | text... | 2011-12-20 22:10:30 
2         | 2          | text... | 2011-12-20 22:10:30 
3         | 2          | text... | 2011-12-21 22:10:30 
4         | 2          | text... | 2011-12-22 22:10:30 
5         | 2          | text... | 2011-12-23 22:10:30
```

To get the latest two updates for a specific project I use:

```
SELECT update_id, title, content, date
FROM updates
WHERE project_id = 2
ORDER BY date DESC
LIMIT 2
```

Now, I want to dynamically add a 'update_time' column to the results, with the values "LATEST" or "PREVIOUS" based on if it is the latest update or the one before that,
like this:

```
update_time | update_id | content | date
------------------------------------------------------
LATEST      | 5          | text... | 2011-12-23 22:10:30 
PREVIOUS    | 4          | text... | 2011-12-22 22:10:30
```

Only if you want to know why I need this: [MySQL: Select row by id with previous and next rows by date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8673571/mysql-select-row-by-id-with-previous-and-next-rows-by-date)

Comment: Seems like a job most easily done client-side.

Comment: @Sergei: You also commented on my previous question, you also said that it is not possible, but it was. Please, stop posting this kind of comments, i dont know what do you mean client-side, javascript?? anyways, my question is how to do it in MySQL, not how else i can do it.

Comment: Client in this case is PHP or similar.

Comment: Its not the same question... but feel free to post your answer.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev confused as to why you've mentioned "client" and PHP since PHP is a server side language, not client side. In any case the question relates to doing it through MySQL.

Comment: @Andy: PHP is mysql's client. Mysql is the server in this interaction. It's all relative :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's some smart-ass SQL. It select 'LATEST' for the first row, and 'PREVIOUS' for all others (should we have more than one of them).

```
SELECT IF(@rownum = 0, 'LATEST', 'PREVIOUS') update_time, update_id, 
       title, content, date, (@rownum := @rownum + 1) r
FROM updates, (SELECT @rownum := 0) dummy
WHERE project_id = 2
ORDER BY date DESC
LIMIT 2
```

Also it adds another column to the resultset. Hope it's not a problem.

Comment: This query is 10 times faster that the one proposed by @ypercube, thanks! If you have the time, please take a look at my previous question, maybe you can improve the query there also, i will accept your answer.

Comment: Could you get me a sample data dump, so that I can play with real data? :)

Comment: @Jonathan: You'll need a `(project_id, date`) compound index for this query (and my version as well).

Comment: @ypercube: This query is working, that means that I already have a (project_id, date) compound index??

Comment: The index would increase performance of this query. We can't know if you have an index or not.

Answer (score 1):

Well @Sergei is quite correct but if you insist, there are lots of ways to do this. Here's a quick one

Declare two variables of the same type as `Date` in your table, get the correcsponsing rcords and then union them. There's probably some really clever sql to do it an other way.

NB my mysql is rusty so you might have to how to this stuff.

```
Declare @Latest Date?
Declare @Previous Date?

Select @Latest = Select Max(`Date`) Where Product_ID = 2
Select @Previous = Select Max(`Date`) Where Product_ID = 2 and `Date` < @Latest

SELECT 'Latest' as Update_time,update_id, title, content, date
FROM updates
WHERE project_id = 2 and `Date` = @Latest
Union
SELECT 'Previous' update_id, title, content, date
FROM updates
WHERE project_id = 2 and `Date` = @Previous
```

Messy for something you could do client side in seconds...

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 'LATEST' AS update_time
     , update_id, title, content, `date`
FROM updates
WHERE project_id = 2 
ORDER BY `date` DESC
LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0

UNION 

SELECT 'PREVIOUS'
     , update_id, title, content, `date`
FROM updates
WHERE project_id = 2 
ORDER BY `date` DESC
LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1
```

---

It's not good to use reserved words like `DATE` for column or table names. MySQL lets you go with it but other DBMS may not (or MySQL with different settings).